# How to model room heat (with pump) problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, heat-equation, steady-state

I'm trying to model a problem where a pump is being used to remove heat from a room at a rate of $R$. This pump uses an automated system that only activates when the outside temperature reaches some point $T_{outside}$. The pump then continues to operate so that the temperature inside the room $T_{inside}$ reaches a balance between the heat being conducted *in* (through walls) and the heat being pumped *out*.

I want to find the "steady/balance/equilibrium" temperature $T_{steady}$ which the pump can maintain for the room if a certain surface area of the room, say $A_{surface}$, is exposed to the outside.

The wall materials would have certain thermal conductivities, thickness, etc., and these would all have their own values.

How would I model this problem? What type of problem is this? What particular equations would I use? Is this modelled using partial differential equations? Reference to a specific textbook chapter or online document that deals with this specific type of problem would be greatly appreciated, so that I may study this. I've done my own research, but there's such a large amount of seemingly relevant material that it's difficult to be sure of exactly what I should be using, since I'm not familiar with the mathematics or physics.

In this case, would $T_{outside}$ and $T_{steady}$ be boundary conditions in the hypothetical model? It seems to me that this is reasonable?

I would greatly appreciate it if the modellers here could please take the time to provide information and clarity about this.

Comment: This seems like a typical steady-state heat transfer problem. Are you familiar with the governing equation for heat transfer?

Comment: chapters 4 and 5 here I think cover what you need to know, you might have to backtrack to chapters 1-3 at some points: https://epdf.pub/biological-and-bioenvironmental-heat-and-mass-transfer.html

Comment: @ZachFavakeh Thanks for the comment. I'm familiar with the *heat equation* PDE https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation , but not the steady-state heat transfer problem.

Comment: The heat equation I think is the same/similar. Check out this resource for clarification: https://www.cheric.org/files/education/cyberlecture/e201501/e201501-201.pdf

Comment: @ZachFavakeh Thanks for the resource! Are chapters 3 and 4 the relevant ones?

Comment: Anyway, sorry about that, please look at chapters 3 and 4 for steady-state heat transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to balance the heat flows into and out of the room.  The heat flow out is the capacity of the heat pump, which may depend on the temperature differential it is working against.  The heat flow in is conduction through the walls.  You can assess the [R-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-value_(insulation)) of each wall based on its construction.  The heat flow through that wall is then the temperature difference across the wall times the wall area divided by the R value.  If you have windows in the sun, you also need to compute the heat that comes in as light and is absorbed in the room.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, that's a good point: windows will also have to be considered. I think Zach Favakeh's idea of this being a steady-state heat transfer problem is correct. Do you know how windows would be factored into a steady-state heat transfer problem?

Comment: Just as much as I said.  You asses the energy that comes in and stays.  I don't know how that is done.

Comment: Both the pump and the windows would both be modelled in the generation/depletion term of the governing equation. They would be given as a rate in joules/s, I believe.

Comment: @ZachFavakeh Ahh, I see. Thank you for all of your help, Zach and Ross! Time to start reading!

Comment: No problem. Post an update if you get stuck down the road.

Comment: @ZachFavakeh Will do! Thanks again!

Comment: If the outer surface of the wall is in sunlight it can be hotter than the outside air.  In that case you need to use its temperature for the equation.

Comment: @RossMillikan Got it! Thanks!